# Python multiprocessing passing database cursor object

Tags: python, mysql, database

I have a Queue that gets populated with `getq()` method. The data populated in this queue needs to be inserted into database.

I'm trying to spawn few Processes and insert the data into database. Since total data is around 100MB, doing parallel processing saves in-memory!

I'm using SQL Server, with `pymssql` library on Python 2.7.

The below is my code

```
def worker(queue, db_queue):
    db = get_db()
    cursor = db.cursor()
    db_queue.put(db)
    while True:
        data = queue.get()
        # perform database operations inside a function
        queue.task_done()

def main():
    queue = JoinableQueue()
    db_queue = Queue()
    for _ in range(10):
        p = Process(target=worker, args=(queue, db_queue))
        p.daemon = True
        p.start()
    getq(q)
    queue.join()

    while not db_queue.empty():
          db_queue.get().commit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

When I am putting `db` aka connection objects into a `multiprocessing.Queue`, and getting it back in the main process, the connection is getting closed!

My basic intention is to insert all the data into database using several processes. Only after successful insertions in all processes, commit them. If even one fails to commit, rollback everything!

I'm not sure where things are going wrong.
Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> while True:
>     data = queue.get()
>     # perform database operations inside a function
>     queue.task_done()
> db.commit()    # unreachable
> ```

Looks to me that you are never committing to the database, since you are always spinning in the `while True` loop.

Comment: aha, I didn't notice that. could you please look into 2nd part of the question. I will rephrase the question.